# Создание таблицы с датой

Tags: mysql, sql

Пытаюсь создать таблицу в которой одним из полей будет поле дата-время, но получаю ошибку, много разных вариантов синтаксиса перепробовал, но результат один. Запрос делаю так:

```
create table dialog_1_3 (
  id BIGINT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  from_login varchar(32),
  who_login varchar(32),
  message varchar(8192),
  date_time DATETIME()
);
```

Comment: Скобки возле DATETIME уберите. Т.е.`create table dialog_1_3 (  id BIGINT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, from_login varchar(32), who_login varchar(32), message varchar(8192), date_time DATETIME  );`

Comment: А какой диалект SQL используется? MySQL?

Comment: использую MySQL

Answer (score 1):

Вам необходимо убрать круглые скобки после типа `DATETIME`

```
create table dialog_1_3 (
  id BIGINT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  from_login varchar(32),
  who_login varchar(32),
  message varchar(8192),
  date_time DATETIME
);
```

Круглые скобки после типа столбца обычно используются если необходимо передать его размер или количество символов, которые будут отводится под столбец при консольном выводе. У типа `DATETIME` такая возможность не предусматривается синтаксисом, поэтому возвращается ошибка.